# Checking that a differential form is holomorphic on an algebraic curve and that it extends to a holomorphic form on its compactification

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, projective-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Consider the following algebraic curve:

$$C=\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | x^3+y^3+3\lambda xy + 1=0 \right\} $$

…where $\lambda^3 \neq -1$. I think this is called the Hesse pencil, and it’s a Riemann surface. Then:

1. I’m told that the differential form

$$\frac{dx}{y^2+\lambda x}=-\frac{dy}{x^2+\lambda y}$$

is a holomorphic differential form on $C$. How do I actually check that? I know from Miranda’s book that a holomorphic $1$-form on a Riemann surface $X$ is a collection of holomorphic $1$-forms (in the complex-analytic sense) on each chart such that they correctly transform to each other when two charts have overlapping domains. I also know that a holomorphic $1$-form on an open set $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ is an expression of the form $\omega = f(z)dz$.

However, I’m not sure how to apply this to this case. Are the expressions $\frac{dx}{y^2+\lambda x}$ and $\frac{dy}{x^2+\lambda y}$ locally defined (in one chart given by, I guess, the coordinates $(x,y))$? In that case, if I understand correctly, I should check that the functions $\frac{1}{y^2+\lambda x}$ and $-\frac{1}{x^2+\lambda y}$ are holomorphic over $C$, but I don’t really know how to do that since they’re defined on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and hence applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations doesn’t seem to be the way to go here (I usually check that $\partial f/\partial \bar{z}=0$ to see that a function $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$… should I do this for $x$ and $y$ in the case of $f(x,y)$?).

2. I’m also told that this holomorphic differential form extends to a holomorphic differential form on the compactification of $C$, which I think is the locus in $\mathbb{PC}^2$ of the homogenization of $x^3+y^3+3\lambda xy + 1$, that is

$$\hat{C}=\left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{PC}^2 | x^3+y^3+z^3+3\lambda xyz=0 \right\} $$

Again, I’m not sure how to do that. I know that in theory, I should check that the differential form transforms to a holomorphic form in some coordinates including the points at infinity, but I haven’t seen any example of this kind of computation (I’m kind of new to Riemann surfaces). Any help or references to a similar example would be appreciated.

Comment: The pencil comes from varying the parameter $\lambda$. Yes, $dx/(y^2+\lambda x)$ is a holomorphic $1$-form wherever $\lambda x\ne y$ because it's the restriction to $C$ of a holomorphic form on $\Bbb C^2$. Where that happens, you use the alternative expression $-dy/(x^2+\lambda y)$.  Can we have $y^2+\lambda x = x^2 +\lambda y = 0$? By the way, you say *normalization* in the title, but the curve is already smooth.

Comment: @TedShifrin Should I say ‘compactification’ then? And, you mean that since you can’t have $y^2+\lambda x = x^2+\lambda y = 0$, then $1/(y^2+\lambda x)$ and $1/(x^2+\lambda y)$ are holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: I don’t follow why we can use the alternative expression $-dy/(x^2+\lambda y)$.

Comment: They are holomorphic away from the zeroes of the respective denominators. My point was that they cannot vanish simultaneously (except at the origin, which is not on $C$). Did you prove that those two $1$-forms are equal on $C$ wherever they’re both defined?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, I didn’t prove it, I just read it on the statement of the problem. I don’t really see why they’re equal on $C$.

Comment: I think you need some practice with differential forms before continuing further. If $C$ is given by $f=0$, what is the $1$-form $df$ on $C$?

Comment: You need to compute in coordinates at the three points on the line at jnfinity.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh okay, it is $df=0$, and then if $C$ is given by $f=x^3+y^3+3\lambda xy+1$, then $df=3((x^2+\lambda y)dx + (y^2+\lambda x)dy)=0$ on $C$ and that’s why $dx/(y^2+\lambda x)=-dy/(x^2+\lambda y)$ on $C$, is that what you mean? You’re right that I need more practice. I think I already see why the differential form defined by those expressions is holomorphic on $C$ then… but why does it extend to a holomorphic form on $\hat{C}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I calculated the points on the line at infinity and found $(1:-1:0)$ and $(1 :( 1 \pm i\sqrt{3})/2 :0)$. I’m unsure about what coordinates should I use though. I thought since $x \neq 0$, I could take $(x:y:1)=(1:y/x:1/x):=(1: \alpha: \beta)$, and then since $dx=-d\alpha / \alpha^2$ and $y=\beta x =\beta / \alpha$, we would have $dx/(y^2+ \lambda x)=-d\alpha / (\beta^2+ \lambda \alpha)$, is that the correct idea so far?

Comment: You have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ reversed? But, yes, this is the right analysis, otherwise.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes! $\alpha:=1/x$ and $\beta:=y/x$.